# Riemann integrability and discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

$g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded and $\alpha:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ non-decreasing. Assume $ g \in \mathbb{R}_\alpha[\delta,1]$ for every $\delta > 0$.

I showed that $g\in\mathbb{R}_\alpha[0,1]$ if $\alpha$ is continous at 0. Now I need to find a pair $(g,\alpha)$ which shows that $g\not\in\mathbb{R}_\alpha[0,1]$ if $\alpha$ is not continuous at 0

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as $g$ is both bounded and continuous, then $g \in \mathcal{R}_\alpha([0,1])$ even if $\alpha$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$.

However, if both $g$ and $\alpha$ are discontinuous (from the right) at $x =0$, then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral may not exist.

For example, take

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1 , &x = 0\\ 0, & 0 < x \leqslant 1 \end{cases}, \quad \alpha(x) = \begin{cases}0 , &x = 0\\ 1, & 0 < x \leqslant 1 \end{cases}$$

For any partition $P: 0 = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots <x_n = 1$, since $\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1}) = 0$ for $j > 1$, the upper and lower sums are

$$U(P,g,\alpha) = \sup_{x \in [0,x_1]}g(x) \,\,( \alpha(x_1) - \alpha(0)) = 1\cdot 1=1 ,$$

and

$$L(P,g,\alpha) = \inf_{x \in [0,x_1]}g(x) \,\,( \alpha(x_1) - \alpha(0)) = 0 \cdot 1 = 0,$$

Thus, the integral fails to exist since there is no partition such that $U(P,g,\alpha) - L(P,g,\alpha) < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon < 1.$

Comment: thanks a ton!!!

Comment: @KaanYolsever: You're welcome.